# Inspect Column under the Inspect tab fixated on json document root

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am working on transforming all json files under a folder. This is just a learning exercise for me regarding basic ADF.

I created a pipeline, added a data flow to it and in the data flow, I added a folder in Azure Data Lake as a dataset. In the source options, I am using the wildcard path to choose only the json files within the folder(Kept the file name argument in source empty for this to work). When I did a Data Preview, I saw the json properly with the elements.

Then I added a select transformation from the Data source. Nothing special but to just pick out the elements in the json as columns. But here I am facing issue.

This is my select settings page:

[image: Select Settings page]

We can clearly see that I chose one string within the complex object(Location is the head object and country is the string within it). However, when I see the Inspect tab, it considers the Country as complex object by considering the input column as Location. This is the inspect page:

[image: Inspect Tab Display]

Why I am seeing this as a complex object in Inspect whereas the select option clearly says Country is a string in the settings page? What is it I am doing wrong or how to correct this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you files are nested JSON(Location is the head object and country is the string within it), The source Projection/Inspect also should be a complex column:
[image]

Off course the output of the Select is complex type column.
[image]

HTH.

Comment: Is there a way to process the complex type and fetch only the Country string out as a column?

Comment: @thiruvenkadam No, there isn't. But don't worry about that, `Country` 's actually fetched as a string column.  Please see `Country == String `, the complex type is for 'LOCATION'.